# New user posting spam links

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

While in the review queue for "Late Answers", I noticed [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803278/andy) come up twice in a row, and both Late Answers were identical, link-only answers. I thought it odd so I checked his profile and found yet another answer that was identical to the other two. All three answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476737/using-the-sql-like-operator-with/35109946#35109946), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560564/how-to-use-the-like-operator-in-sql/35109897#35109897) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803489/sql-like-query-using-where-the-search-criteria-contains/35109874#35109874).

I investigated the link that the user supplied and it is for SQL courses offered by, what one would assume is, the same person who posted the answer, "Andy".

Before investigating further I flagged the first two answers as 'Low Quality', but I now realize that I should have probably flagged them as spam. Although, I was able to flag the third as spam.

How does one bring this user/the questions to attention of moderators after already raising flags? My concern is that the question marked as spam will be properly handled, but the others might go unnoticed...unless other reviewers mark it as spam, of course!

Is mentioning it here enough? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning it here works, but it's a fairly inconvenient and slow way to go about it. In these cases, I usually flag one of the posts with a flag like this:

> 3/3 of this user's answers link to 9nl.me. Probably a good idea to delete + destroy.

Or similar. This lets a moderator know that something isn't right here, and they can take action as they see fit (I also suggest a course of action, just to make things a little easier).

In cases where you've already flagged all their posts, and thus can't cast another flag, you might consider entering a room like the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or [Charcoal HQ](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and explaining the situation. There are plenty of people there who have extra flags and know what to do.

They're friendly, too.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know about the room option; I wasn't aware of such a thing and in this case it would have been perfect.

Comment: Aside: 9nl.me isn't the thing being promoted, it's a URL shortener.

Comment: @LiveForever: And as such a hint at worse things. Though, yes.